# Understanding Tkinter window responsiveness when running a background thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to create a GUI that is continually updated from a computation thread. In order to keep the GUI responsive, I create an event in each loop of this thread that tells the main thread (in which the Tkinter window was created) to update the GUI with the computed data. The structure of the thread looks like this:

```
class background_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent, stopper):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.parent  = parent
        self.stopper = stopper

        ### Init. variables ###

    def run(self):
        while(not self.stopper.is_set()):

            ### Compute data ###

            root.event_generate("<<update_gui>>", when = "now")
```

This works nicely, but I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of my Tkinter window when the thread is running. First, even though my `mainloop()` is still responsive (I get approximately 40 frames per second), the window itself is not responsive at all. By this, I mean that it's not really possible to drag it nor to close it. What is the reason for this and is there any way to prevent it?

One of the problems arising from this is that I have to stop the thread before closing the window. For this, I use a button that toggles its execution:

```
def callback_toggle_thread(self, event):    
    if(not self.background_thread.isAlive()):
        self.background_thread.start()
    else:
        self.stopper.set()
```

But if I try to redefine the window close button protocole:

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

def on_closing():
    if(self.background_thread.isAlive()):
        self.stopper.set()                  # Asks the thread to stop
        self.background_thread.join()       # Waits for the thread to stop

    root.destroy()                          # Closes the window
```

the program just freezes. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I think some stuff got messed up in making simple examples, you are defining `on_closing` after using it and `callback_toggle_thread` seems to be possibly trying to start the thread after it finishes so in the example code there are quite a few things you are doing wrong.

Comment: but for the actual question it is possible you need a few `root.update()` calls from the background thread because I think the window will only try to process user input etc. when there are no active tasks (like your thread) including the close protocol.

Comment: In fact, once the thread has been started and stopped once, 'callback_toggle_thread' returns an error, but this is not an issue for now. (I would simply have to create a new `background_thread` object). I didn't show my entire code to simplify things, but `on_closing` is called correctly when I try to close the window. I tried it by replacing its content with a simple `print` to the console.

Comment: Wow, that was much simpler than I thought. Adding a `root.update()` right after `root.event_generate()` solved everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897987/understanding-tkinter-window-responsiveness-when-running-a-background-thread?noredirect=1#comment59461418_35897987) if you call `root.update()` after generating the event in the background thread it will force the application to update itself. This [fixed the original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897987/understanding-tkinter-window-responsiveness-when-running-a-background-thread?noredirect=1#comment59461737_35897987) although I can't walk through the specific flow of execution since the example code isn't enough to test.